# Can't click on NavigationDrawer Items

Tags: android, xml

My navigation drawer is transparent for some reason and if I try to click it if there is a view under it it doesn't register the click. I don't really know why it is so transparent, but whatever.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#311b92"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_homescreen_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_homescreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Move the `<include>` to inside the `<DrawerLayout>`, before the `<NavigationView>`. You don't need the `<FrameLayout>` then.

Comment: @MikeM. Great, that fixed it!

Comment: Yeah, the main content - whatever you want the drawer to open over - always goes inside the `<DrawerLayout>` as the first child.